# How to replace all domains with pattern in a XML string in Java?

Tags: java, regex, xml, parsing, url

I have an XML output like this (**<xml> element or xlink:href attribute are just fiction and you cannot rely on them to create regex pattern.**)

```
<xml>http://localhost:8080/def/abc/xyx</xml>
<element xlink:href="http://localhostABCDEF/def/ABC/XYZ">Some Text</element>
...
```

What I want to do is using Java regex to replace the domain pattern (I don't know about existing domains):

```
"http(s)?://.*/def/.*
```

with an input domain (e.g: http://google.com/def) and the result will be:

```
<xml>http://google.com/def/abc/xyx</xml>
<element xlink:href="http://google.com.com/def/ABC/XYZ">Some Text</element>
...
```

How can I do it? I think Regex in Java can do or String.replaceAll (but this one seems not possible).

Comment: I'd use an XML parser (DOM if your file is small, event-driven otherwise) and for each element that you know will contain the URL (in your case, `xml` apparently), initialize a `URL` object with that element, get the `path` of the `URL` object, and construct again with a different domain.

Comment: Use back references in your regex "http(s)?://(.*)/def/.*"

Comment: Epic answer to a closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Why is in your `xml` tags path `/def/abc/xyx` lowercase and in `href` uppercase `/def/ABC/XYZ`?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz you didn't put any backreferences in what you posted, you just copied the original regex and pasted it. Am I missing something?

Comment: @S.Kablar that is what makes it is difficult as you don't know the parts before and after '/def'.

Comment: You want to replace everything before and after `def`?

Comment: @S.Kablar I want to keep the part after 'def' and replace the domain before 'def' with input domain.

Comment: Modify entire html tag or you extracted links to be edited?

Comment: @S.Kablar I don't want to extract, I want to replace link in the input XML string directly, so it is a modification.

Comment: yes, you are missing the parenthesis around the host part of the pattern. In fact, this would be more correct since you don need to capture the s: `"http[s]?://(.*)/def/.*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, this could be done with Regex and it is simple enough than parsing XML document. Here is the answer:

```
String text = "<epsg:CommonMetaData>\n"
            + "      <epsg:type>geographic 2D</epsg:type>\n"
            + "      <epsg:informationSource>EPSG. See 3D CRS for original information source.</epsg:informationSource>\n"
            + "      <epsg:revisionDate>2007-08-27</epsg:revisionDate>\n"
            + "      <epsg:changes>\n"
            + "        <epsg:changeID xlink:href=\"http://www.opengis.net/def/change-request/EPSG/0/2002.151\"/>\n"
            + "        <epsg:changeID xlink:href=\"http://www.opengis.net/def/change-request/EPSG/0/2003.370\"/>\n"
            + "        <epsg:changeID xlink:href=\"http://www.opengis.net/def/change-request/EPSG/0/2006.810\"/>\n"
            + "        <epsg:changeID xlink:href=\"http://www.opengis.net/def/change-request/EPSG/0/2007.079\"/>\n"
            + "      </epsg:changes>\n"
            + "      <epsg:show>true</epsg:show>\n"
            + "      <epsg:isDeprecated>false</epsg:isDeprecated>\n"
            + "    </epsg:CommonMetaData>\n"
            + "  </gml:metaDataProperty>\n"
            + "  <gml:metaDataProperty>\n"
            + "    <epsg:CRSMetaData>\n"
            + "      <epsg:projectionConversion xlink:href=\"http://www.opengis.net/def/coordinateOperation/EPSG/0/15593\"/>\n"
            + "      <epsg:sourceGeographicCRS xlink:href=\"http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/4979\"/>\n"
            + "    </epsg:CRSMetaData>\n"
            + "  </gml:metaDataProperty>"
            + "<gml:identifier codeSpace=\"OGP\">http://www.opengis.net/def/area/EPSG/0/1262</gml:identifier>";

    String patternString1 = "(http(s)?://.*/def/.*)";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

    String prefixDomain = "http://localhost:8080/def";

    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    while (matcher.find()) {
        String url = prefixDomain + matcher.group(1).split("def")[1];
        matcher.appendReplacement(sb, url);
        System.out.println(url);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(sb);
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

which returns output https://www.diffchecker.com/CyJ8fY8p

Answer (score 0):

**Regex**: [`http[s]?:\/{2}.+\/def`](https://regex101.com/r/pCsrTW/2/) **Substitution**: `http://google.com/def`

**Details**:

- `?` Matches between zero and one times
- `[]` Match a single character present in the list
- `.` Matches any character
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

**Java code**:

```
String domain = "http://google.com/def";
String html = "<xml>http://localhost:8080/def/abc/xyx</xml>\r\n<element xlink:href=\"http://localhostABCDEF/def/ABC/XYZ\">Some Text</element>";

html = html.replaceAll("http[s]?:\\/{2}.+\\/def", domain);
System.out.print(html);
```

**Output**:

```
<xml>http://google.com/def/abc/xyx</xml>
<element xlink:href="http://google.com/def/ABC/XYZ">Some Text</element>
```

Comment: I appreciate about your effort, but <xml> element or xlink:href attribute are just fiction and you cannot rely on them to create regex pattern. They could be different element names, attributes and what I want is to replace the domain name in XML string which seems XPath is possible.

Comment: @Bằng Rikimaru Updated.